# boost::adaptor::filtered core dumps with boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper "Assertion `m_impl' failed"

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-range

I get an assertion failure inside `boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper` when I run this code. The assertion appears to be checking that the functor has been initialized inside the filter object.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template<class RangeType>
static auto get_range_and_range_size(const RangeType& in_range, std::input_iterator_tag) -> auto {
    /*
     * we have an InputRange, but we need to know the size of the range.
     * so we eagerly copy the values into a vector so we can get the size of the range
     * and also return the range.
     * */
    auto out_range = std::vector<decltype(*std::begin(in_range))>(
        std::begin(in_range),
        std::end(in_range)
    );

    return std::make_tuple(std::move(out_range), out_range.size());
}

template<class RangeType>
static auto get_range_and_range_size(const RangeType& in_range, std::forward_iterator_tag) -> auto {
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(in_range), boost::distance(in_range));
}

struct Cache {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m_map;

    template<class RangeT>
    auto Insert(RangeT in_range) -> void {
        typename std::iterator_traits<
            decltype(std::begin(in_range))
        >::iterator_category iterator_category;

        std::cout << "No core dump yet!\n";

        auto range_and_range_size = get_range_and_range_size(
            boost::adaptors::filter(
                in_range,
                /*
                 * filter out any keys that are already in the cache and NOT TTLed yet
                 * */
                [this](const auto& key_value) -> bool {
                    const auto find_itr = m_map.find(key_value.first);

                    return (m_map.end() == find_itr)    /*  the key was not in the cache    */
                           || hasTTLed(find_itr->second);  /*  the key was in the cache but its value has TTLed  */
                }
            ),
            iterator_category
        );

        for(auto&& key_value : std::get<0>(range_and_range_size)) {
            m_map.emplace(key_value);
        }

        std::cout << "Can't reach this code. :(\n";
    }

    auto hasTTLed(int) const noexcept -> bool {
        /*
         *  TTL impl goes here
         */
        return false;
    }
};

auto main(int, char*[]) -> int {
    Cache a{};

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{
        {0, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {2, 2},
        {3, 3}
    };

    a.Insert(v);

    std::map<int, int> b{
        {0, 1},
        {1, 0},
        {2, 1},
        {3, 1}
    };

    a.Insert(b);
}
```

I get this with whatever version of boost that coliru uses, as well as 1.60.

Reproduced on coliru [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b82943add39d44).

Can you help me understand a) what is happening here, and b) how I fix it?

Comment: From the name of the assertion failure, my guess is the `filter` adaptor wants a default constructible predicate, and a lambda is not default constructible.

Comment: It doesn't name that requirement anywhere in the documentation, though.

Comment: (nitpicking here, but a lambda could be default constructible if it had no captures)

Comment: See [this](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2011/05/68580.php). The documentation for `filter_iterator` does mention the predicate needs to be default constructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a lifetimes issue.

The issue was in `get_range_and_range_size`, which was capturing a `const RangeType&` when it should have been capturing a `RangeType&&`. Returning a `std::ref` to a temporary captured that way was causing calls to uninitialized ranges in the code acting on `range_and_range_size`.

These definitions of `get_range_and_range_size` solve the problem.

```
template<class RangeType>
static auto get_range_and_range_size(RangeType&& in_range, std::input_iterator_tag) -> auto {
    /*
     * we have an InputRange, but we need to know the size of the range.
     * so we eagerly copy the values into a vector so we can get the size of the range
     * and also return the range.
     * */
    auto out_range = std::vector<decltype(*std::begin(in_range))>(
        std::begin(in_range),
        std::end(in_range)
    );

    const auto out_size = out_range.size(); /*  capture the value before moving the container   */
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(out_range), out_size);
}

template<class RangeType>
static auto get_range_and_range_size(RangeType&& in_range, std::forward_iterator_tag) -> auto {
    const auto size = boost::distance(in_range); /*  capture the value before moving the container   */
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(in_range), size);
}
```

Comment: You should `std::forward<RangeType>(in_range)` when calling `make_tuple` in the second overload. And I was wrong in my earlier comment about having to fetch `size()` separately. `make_tuple` perfect forwards its arguments, so you're only binding references when you call it, no move construction actually takes place, so calling `.size()` in the second argument is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I presume in the case of the `input_iterator_tag` function I still need to `std::move` the vector, since it is not a temporary.